How to get Win32 Project in Visual Studio 2022
I'm trying to follow the instructions of the following question: How can I combine several individual .ico files into a single file?
The top answer there states the following:

You need to build a DLL that contains multiple icons as resources.  That can be done from Visual Studio via these instructions.  Other Windows development tools that can create a DLL should be able to do the same thing.

In these instructions, it says

To create a resource-only DLL [in Visual Studio], you create a new Win32 DLL (non-MFC) project and add your resources to the project.

Select Win32 Project in the New Project dialog box and specify a DLL project type in the Win32 Project Wizard.


But clicking on New Project in Visual Studio, I struggle to find the "Win32 Project" in the listing that they are referring to:

How can I find such a project? I am using Visual Studio 2022.

What version of Visual Studio are you running? The instructions you’re trying to follow are not compatible with Visual Studio 2019, 2022, and Visual Studio Code. [Edit] your question and include enough information to answer your question

@Ramhound I am indeed using VS2022 - edited to say so. How might I do this in VS2022?

Class Library will create a DLL. You can choose which architectures you want to support within the project. Those instructions are for MSC++ applications not C# so make sure you have installed the appropriate compiler. Here are the instructions you should be using

Go to Tools > Get Tools and Features and make sure that "Desktop Development with C++" has been installed. That should add the additional project templates you are looking for.
